# Is there a way to bypass internet explorer startup home pages when desired?

Tags: internet-explorer, boot, internet-explorer-9

I have 5 home page tabs that launch when I startup Internet Explorer. Normally this is fine, but other times I do not want the multiple startup pages launching. Is there a way to bypass the startup pages when starting up internet explorer? Maybe there is a key I can hold down when starting IE that will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a key combo that would help with this. What you *can* do instead is create a shortcut to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" about:blank
```

If you assign a keyboard shortcut to this, you can quickly launch a copy of IE that will skip any assigned home pages only for that session.